# Return array based on v-for selected options

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

i'm trying to loop into an array of data , and i have other fileds that are selecteble based on the first selected option.

But when i change one chiled, all other seletion filed reseted to the default empty.

here is the code that im using :

**the Template :**

```
<div class="row col-12" v-for="(ROW,rindex) in PARENT_ROWS" :key="rindex">
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 ">
        <label for="">CARS</label>
        <select2 :options="Cars" v-model="ROW['CATALOG_NAME']" required></select2>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-2 ">
        <label for="" v-if="ROW['build_for']=='A'">its for A</label>
        <select2 :options="optionsfor(ROW['CATALOG_NAME'])" v-model="ROW['RELATION']" required></select2>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-md-2 ">
        <label for="">Time</label>
        <select2 :options="timesFor(ROW['CATALOG_NAME'])" v-model="ROW['TIME']" required></select2>
    </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2" v-if="ROW['build_for']!='A'">
        <label for="">Detail</label>
        <select2 :options="detailsFor(ROW['CATALOG_NAME'])" v-model="ROW['DETAIL']" required></select2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The Script**

```
<script>
export default {
    name : "Cars.CarsBuilder",
    data(){
        return {
            indexData:{
                cars : [],
            }
        }
    },
    created(){
        axios.post(URL_TO_API).then(response=>{
            this.indexData.cars = response.data;
             /**
             * data structure
             [
                 'CAR_NAME_1':  [
                     {TYPE_DATA:'',MDATA:''},
                     {TYPE_DATA:'',MDATA:''},
                     {TYPE_DATA:'',MDATA:''},
                 ],
                 'CAR_NAME_2':  [
                     {TYPE_DATA:'',MDATA:''},
                     {TYPE_DATA:'',MDATA:''},
                     {TYPE_DATA:'',MDATA:''},
                 ],
             ]
             */
        })
    },
    methods:{
        optionsfor(catalog_name){
            let find = this.$clone(this.indexData.cars[catalog_name]).filter(f=>f.TYPE_DATA=="C1");
            return find.reduce(function(obj,item){
                obj.push({id:item.MC1,text:item.MC1});
                return obj;
            },[]);
        },
        timesFor(catalog_name){
            let find = this.$clone(this.indexData.cars[catalog_name]).filter(f=>f.TYPE_DATA=="C2");
            return find.reduce(function(obj,item){
                obj.push({id:item.MC2,text:item.MC2});
                return obj;
            },[]);
        },
        detailsFor(catalog_name){
            let find = this.$clone(this.indexData.cars[catalog_name]).filter(f=>f.TYPE_DATA=="C3");
            return find.reduce(function(obj,item){
                obj.push({id:item.MC3,text:item.MC3});
                return obj;
            },[]);
        },
    },
}
```

When the user select a Car , i get into the Cars parent by Key, then making some filters on it to get more options like Details , Time and Relation.

The problem occured when i select Detail or Time or Relation , all others selection go default/empty.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind reactive properties to your filters.

Then reference those in your template, or use a computed property that includes the items and the filter parameters.

You are using methods, but when you change your filters they wont recompute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i will make change, test and give you my feed-back.

Answer (score 0):

after Steven Spungin answer, i made this change , and it's work for me :

1 - First : adding a new property in data() called : **CarsData** as *Array*.

```
data(){
        return {
            CarsData : [],...} }...
```

2 - Creating a method "**getCar(catalog_name)**" to store Car's data by name using the same methods already created ( because we can't pass parameter to computed property ) if its not in the CarsData collection.

```
getCar(catalog_name){
            if(catalog_name==null || catalog_name==''){return;}
            if(!this.CarsData.hasOwnProperty(catalog_name)){
                this.CarsData[catalog_name] = {
                    optionsfor : this.optionsfor(catalog_name),
                    timesFor: this.timesFor(catalog_name),
                    detailsFor: this.detailsFor(catalog_name),
                };
            }
        }
```

3 - add **:set="getCar(ROW['CATALOG_NAME'])** in the CARS select option.

```
<select2 :options="Cars" :set="getCar(ROW['CATALOG_NAME'])" v-model="ROW['CATALOG_NAME']" required></select2>
```

4 - Replacing methods calls in selects by property and CatalogName

```
<select2 :options="CarsData[ROW['CATALOG_NAME']].optionsfor" v-model="ROW['RELATION']" required></select2>
<select2 :options="CarsData[ROW['CATALOG_NAME']].timesFor" v-model="ROW['TIME']" required></select2>
<select2 :options="CarsData[ROW['CATALOG_NAME']].detailsFor" v-model="ROW['DETAIL']" required></select2>
```

After the explenation that Steven give, calling method in the template make its using reduce multiple time so the data will always been refreshed, but , by storing it in a property it will be found in memory to be displayed for user.

Thanks for the light.